React konva preview on infinite canvas
I'm currently implementing an infinite canvas feature in react konva. I would like to implement a preview functionality. After users draw on the infinite canvas, I want them to be able to click a button to view a scaled preview of their drawing. However, in this preview, I don't want the canvas to behave like an infinite canvas. Instead, I want the stage to scale based on the drawing, and adjust its position so that the entire drawing fits within the preview viewport. How can I achieve this?
I want a solution for react-konva preview anyone have a answer please share it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
